# Created File Has No Parent?

Tags: java, file, directory, nullpointerexception, parent

In a java program, I create a file with

```
File temp = new File("temp");
temp.createNewFile();
```

Then for some reason when I write

```
File pDir = temp.getParentFile();
```

and pDir is null. I actually want to write

```
File pDir = temp.getParentFile().getParentFile();
```

but that throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: Aren't they automatically created in the working directory? It does create the file there, it just doesn't return any parents.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need a file with a path for that, try getAbsoluteFile.

```
File pDir = temp.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I'll accept as soon as I am able to.

Comment: can nayone explain why we can not write temp.getParentFile();

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a file called temp, but it has no path, so there will be no parent path. If you want to put the file in the current directory:

```
File temp = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/temp");
File parent = temp.getParentFile();
```