# Check if file is in (sub)directory

Tags: java

I would like to check whether an existing file is in a specific directory or a subdirectory  of that.

I have two File objects.

```
File dir;
File file;
```

Both are guaranteed to exist. Let's assume

```
dir  = /tmp/dir 
file = /tmp/dir/subdir1/subdir2/file.txt
```

I want this check to return true

For now i am doing the check this way:

```
String canonicalDir = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator;
boolean subdir = file.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(canonicalDir);
```

This seems to work with my limited tests, but i am unsure whether this might make problems on some operating systems. I also do not like that getCanonicalPath() can throw an IOException which i have to handle.

Is there a better way? Possibly in some library?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

In addition to the asnwer from rocketboy, use `getCanonicalPath()` instad of `getAbsolutePath()` so `\dir\dir2\..\file` is converted to `\dir\file`:

```
    boolean areRelated = file.getCanonicalPath().contains(dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator);
    System.out.println(areRelated);
```

or

```
boolean areRelated = child.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(parent.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator);
```

Do not forget to catch any `Exception` with `try {...} catch {...}`.

NOTE: You can use `FileSystem.getSeparator()` instead of `File.separator`. The 'correct' way of doing this will be to get the `getCanonicalPath()` of the directory that you are going to check against as a `String`, then check if ends with a `File.separator` and if not then add `File.separator` to the end of that `String`, to avoid double slashes. This way you skip future odd behaviours if Java decides to return directories with a slash in the end or if your directory string comes from somewhere else than `Java.io.File`.

NOTE2: Thanx to @david for pointing the `File.separator` problem.

Comment: What about `/a` and `/ab/test.txt`?

Comment: @david Will return exactly the same. If you ask for slashes instead of backslashes, I don't know the behaviour, but my recommendation is to use OS native. Java has a function to return the OS native directory separator, but I don't remember it right now.

Comment: My point was not about the direction of the slashes at all; I was giving a counter example that will result in an incorrect answer using the strategy in your answer.

Comment: @david That's why I said that you must use the slash that is native to the OS. If you do it well programmed, you are always going to sanitize user input. If you look at it closer, you will notice that I call `getCanonicalPath()` on `Java.io.File`, so obviously I assume that `Java.io.File` is a valid one because my answer comes from `[...]check whether an existing file[...]`. The work to check that is a valid/existing file (not empty text/using Java native functions to locate the file/checking for native OS slashes when is a direct text input from user/etc..) is the programmers work here.

Comment: You are missing the point again. Is `/ab/test.txt` in a subdirectory of `/a`? Think about it.

Comment: @david Ohhh already got it hahaha. Sorry for the whole "brick" about input sanitization xD Going to edit the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I would create a small utility method:

```
public static boolean isInSubDirectory(File dir, File file) {

    if (file == null)
        return false;

    if (file.equals(dir))
        return true;

    return isInSubDirectory(dir, file.getParentFile());
}
```

Comment: I would first check if the file is actually a file though. And it might not [find the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296949/created-file-has-no-parent). This sounds like a good idea, but it should be part of a bigger solution.

Answer (score 9):

This method looks pretty solid:

```
/**
 * Checks, whether the child directory is a subdirectory of the base 
 * directory.
 *
 * @param base the base directory.
 * @param child the suspected child directory.
 * @return true, if the child is a subdirectory of the base directory.
 * @throws IOException if an IOError occured during the test.
 */
public boolean isSubDirectory(File base, File child)
    throws IOException {
    base = base.getCanonicalFile();
    child = child.getCanonicalFile();

    File parentFile = child;
    while (parentFile != null) {
        if (base.equals(parentFile)) {
            return true;
        }
        parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Source](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Checkswhetherthechilddirectoryisasubdirectoryofthebasedirectory.htm)

It is similar to the solution by dacwe but doesn't use recursion (though that shouldn't make a big difference in this case).

Comment: It worked for me. I would upvoted twice for using a non recursive approach

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to works with file and filenames heavly check apache fileutils and filenameutils libraries. Are full of useful (and portale if portability is mamdatory)  functions

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File root = new File("c:\\test");
    String fileName = "a.txt";
    try {
        boolean recursive = true;

        Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);

        for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            File file = (File) iterator.next();
            if (file.getName().equals(fileName))
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse File Tree starting from your specific DIR.
At Java 7, there is `Files.walkFileTree` method. You have only to write your own visitor
to check if current node is searched file. More doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, however it won't catch every use case e.g. dir = /somedir/../tmp/dir/etc..., unless that's how the file was defined also.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileTest {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final Path dir = Paths.get("/tmp/dir").toAbsolutePath();
        final Path file = Paths.get("/tmp/dir/subdir1/subdir2/file.txt").toAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Dir: " + dir);
        System.out.println("File: " + file);
        final boolean valid = file.startsWith(dir);
        System.out.println("Valid: " + valid);
    }
}
```

In order for the checks to work correctly, you really need to map these using `toRealPath()` or, in your example, `getCanonicalPath()`, but you then have to handle exceptions for these examples which is absolutely correct that you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7+ you can just do this:

```java
file.toPath().startsWith(dir.toPath());
```

Answer (score -1):

How about comparing the paths?

```
    boolean areRelated = file.getAbsolutePath().contains(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println(areRelated);
```

or

```
boolean areRelated = child.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(parent.getAbsolutePath())
```

Comment: This might be problematic for paths that contain stuff like "/tmp/something/../dir" which is possible in my application.

Comment: You can easily use `child.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(parent.getAbsolutePath())` if thats the case.

Comment: Actually getAbsolutePath() will compute all such '/../' tokens and return real absolute path in file system.

Comment: I'm afraid not: `new File("/Users/johndoe/test/../dir").getAbsolutePath()` returns `"/Users/johndoe/test/../dir"`

Comment: You will at least have to use `getCanonicalFile()`!