# Java: Force JFileChooser to one directory and it's sub-folders

Tags: java, swing, directory, jfilechooser

I have created a **JFileChooser** and I want to **restrict** it only in the **user.home** dir and it's **subfolders.**

The selection mode of my JFileChooser is **directories only.**

So far I have used this:

```
//JButton select = new JButton();
final File directorylock = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
JFileChooser browse = new JFileChooser(directorylock);
browse.setFileView(new FileView() {
    @Override
    public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
         return directorylock.equals(f);
    }
});
```

But every time I open the JFileChooser it only shows me the user.home directory **without** it's subfolders and therefore I cannot access them or select them.

**How it should work:** Open JFileChooser and show the user.home directory with all it's subfolders. Be able to access the subfolders and select them. **NOT** be able to access parent folders. of the user.home directory.

I hope someone here knows how this is supposed to be done! :)
Thank you guys in advance :D

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have tried my best to explain my issue and what I am trying to do. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @AndreasNeophytou Maybe you can improve vishal's solution using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227634/check-if-file-is-in-subdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Single Root File Chooser](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/).

You will only ever see the single file you specify in the combo box so you don't confuse the user that you can select a parent directory.

Then You will only be able to select a file in the directory or sub directory of the file you specify when creating the class.

Comment: Good one but it says in the page "Use this approach at your own risk". May be dangerous. ;-P (I'm kidding)

Comment: thank you man, this one worked, I modified their code to suit my needs and I also had to disable the JFileChooser's text field so it would be impossible for superdirectories or accessing parent directories. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this Sample, it's works fine as like you want,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileView;

public class JFileChooserExample {

       private JFrame mainFrame;
       private JLabel headerLabel;
       private JLabel statusLabel;
       private JPanel controlPanel;

       public JFileChooserExample(){
          prepareGUI();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args){
           JFileChooserExample  swingControlDemo = new JFileChooserExample();      
          swingControlDemo.showFileChooserDemo();
       }

       private void prepareGUI(){
          mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
          mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
          mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
          mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                System.exit(0);
             }        
          });    
          headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
          statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);    

          statusLabel.setSize(350,100);

          controlPanel = new JPanel();
          controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

          mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
          mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
          mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
       }

       private void showFileChooserDemo(){
          headerLabel.setText("Control in action: JFileChooser"); 

          final File directorylock = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
          final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser(directorylock);

          fileDialog.setFileView(new FileView() {
                @Override
                public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
                     return directorylock.equals(f);
                }
            });

          JButton showFileDialogButton = new JButton("Open File");
          showFileDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                   java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
                   statusLabel.setText("File Selected :" 
                   + file.getName());
                }
                else{
                   statusLabel.setText("Open command cancelled by user." );           
                }      
             }
          });
          controlPanel.add(showFileDialogButton);
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
       }
    }
```

Out-Put :

[image]

Comment: thank you for this example man, yeah I have tested it and it works! the only issue (not of your code) is that I want to be able to access subdirectories too. Just not parent folders. I want to be able to access every 'child' folder of the user.dir.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Yes, i am sure, parent won't get accessed,

Comment: @YassinHajaj try to understand we can not access parent but able to access child...!!

Comment: Problem is the parent directories are displayed in the combo box, so the user will think they are able to select a different director. This makes the UI confusing.

Answer (score 2):

With a little modification, I think that Vishal Gajera's solution may work.
I've copied a method from [Check if file is in (sub)directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227634/check-if-file-is-in-subdirectory) give by tsauerwein

```
   /**
    * Checks, whether the child directory is a subdirectory of the base 
    * directory.
    *
    * @param base the base directory.
    * @param child the suspected child directory.
    * @return true, if the child is a subdirectory of the base directory.
    * @throws IOException if an IOError occured during the test.
    */
   public boolean isSubDirectory(File base, File child) {

       boolean res = false;

       try {
        base = base.getCanonicalFile();
           child = child.getCanonicalFile();

           File parentFile = child;
           while (!res && parentFile != null) {
               if (base.equals(parentFile)) {
                   res = true;
               }
               parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return res;
   }


 private void showFileChooserDemo(){
      headerLabel.setText("Control in action: JFileChooser"); 

      final File directorylock = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
      final JFileChooser  fileDialog = new JFileChooser(directorylock);

      fileDialog.setFileView(new FileView() {
            @Override
            public Boolean isTraversable(File f) {
                 return isSubDirectory(directorylock, f);
            }
        });

      JButton showFileDialogButton = new JButton("Open File");
      showFileDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int returnVal = fileDialog.showOpenDialog(mainFrame);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
               java.io.File file = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
               statusLabel.setText("File Selected :" 
               + file.getName());
            }
            else{
               statusLabel.setText("Open command cancelled by user." );           
            }      
         }
      });
      controlPanel.add(showFileDialogButton);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }
```