# Having a static "sub-site" in Wicket (i.e.: mounting a directory in Wicket)

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

I'm developing a web application using `Wicket`.

While most of the website is dynamically generated through wicket, I need to have a portion of the site be a normal "static" `html` website. Basically a small "subsite" inside the main website that is not managed by wicket at all, but that, instead, is just a collection of static content (html pages, css, images).

Can this be done? The idea would be to "mount" a certain subpath to point to the sub-site, but I don't know if this is even possible, as the `mountResource()` method wants a Resource as input.

EDIT: I need a solution that allow me to modify the static html files directly on the filesystem, thus the reason I was trying to "mount a directory" via wicket. I cannot simply put the pages in my webapp folder, since that way they end up inside the app's WAR file and every modification to the static pages would need a full deploy every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: @soorapadman, can you elaborate on this? I tried putting my html files in web-inf, but if I go to www.mysite.org/static_html_page.html it just shows me a blank screen....

Comment: sorry for my comments . place it in `web app` folder it should work definitely

Comment: @soorapadman : your solution works, but unfortunately it's not applicable in my case, as I want the static html files to be directly editable on the filesystem, while with your solution they're packaged in the web app WAR file, and a full deploy is needed for every modification to show up (the reason I want a static sub-site is to be able to modify the pages on the fly directly on the filesystem. I will edit my question to explain this). Thanks anyway.

Comment: You don't need a full re-deployment. Via org.​apache.​wicket.​Application.getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency(Duration d) you can tell Wicket to look for changes in your resources and let them reload. This way your changes would be visible after the specified duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I implementet this myself in the end, using a dynamic resource. I'm not an expert of Wicket, so this may be a "bad" solution for some reason, but it seems to work. Posting the code here so other people can use it if they want:

What I did was create this resource:

```
public class DirectoryResolverResource implements IResource {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private File servedDirectory;
    private String urlPrefix;

    //served directory is the directory you want to mount as a static sub-site
    //urlPrefix is the mountpoint where you're going to mount this resource, without the leading "/". E.g.: if you mount your directory in "/help" so that the sub-site URL is www.yoursite.com/pages/help the urlPrefix value must be "help"
    public DirectoryResolverResource(File servedDirectory, String urlPrefix) {
        super();
        if (servedDirectory == null || !servedDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory is null or doesn't exist");
        }
        this.servedDirectory = servedDirectory;
        this.urlPrefix = urlPrefix;
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(Attributes attributes) {
        Url url = attributes.getRequest().getUrl();
        String subPath = "";
        try {
            //we decode the URL by reversing the percent-encoding, so that filenames are properly resolved
            subPath = URLDecoder.decode(url.toString(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Encoding is invalid");
        }

        if (subPath.startsWith(urlPrefix)) {
            subPath = subPath.substring(urlPrefix.length());
        } else {
            throw new AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Url is invalid");
        }

        File file = new File(servedDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + (subPath.startsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + subPath);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            // In case of a directory, redirect to the path ending in "/", otherwise browsers will fail to resolve relative paths in the page
            if (!subPath.endsWith("/")) {
                throw new RedirectToUrlException("." + (subPath.isEmpty() ? "/" + urlPrefix : subPath) + "/", HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            }
            // no specific file specified, try to return index.html
            file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), "index.html");
        }
        if (!file.exists() || file.isDirectory()) {
            // file not found
            throw new AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "Resource not found");
        }

        if (!FSManager.isInSubDirectory(servedDirectory, file)) {
            // Security check: user is trying to escape the served directory via a non-canonical path
            throw new AbortWithHttpErrorCodeException(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access to this resource is forbidden");
        }

        // Serve the file
        FileResourceStream fileResourceStream = new FileResourceStream(file);
        ResourceStreamResource resource = new ResourceStreamResource(fileResourceStream);
        resource.respond(attributes);
    }

}
```

You can mount this resource like this:

```
mountResource("/help", new ResourceReference("helpres") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public IResource getResource() {
                    return new DirectoryResolverResource(helpDir, "help");
                }
            });
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.
Any improvements/comments/corrections/constructive criticisms are higly appreciated!

NOTE: the `isInSubDirectory()` method just checks if a file is inside a certain directory tree. Won't bore you with the details, you can find implementations of such method here: [Check if file is in (sub)directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18227634/300741)