# How to check if a file exists within a subdirectory of a directory in Java?

Tags: java

This is my current code:

```
File f = new File(folder, fileName);
if (!f.exists()) {
    log.warn("Unable to find file");
} 
else{
    f.delete();
}
```

My problem is that this will always be true in the current context since I have two subfolders that have been generated and hashed. So let's assume I have a leading directory called "data storage" with two sub-directories with randomly hashed names. The file is within the two subdirectories. Is there an easy way to check if my file is within an entire directory, including sub-directories?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if file is in (sub)directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227634/check-if-file-is-in-subdirectory)

Comment: Try to avoid the old cumbersome file api (`File`). It got replaced by NIO (`Files`, `Path`). Its easier to use, has better error messages and less irritating behavior.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Files.walk()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...))

```
Path folderPath = folder.toPath();
boolean containsFile = Files.walk(folderPath)
                              .anyMatch(p -> p.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
File f = new File("yourfilepath/filename.ext");
if(f.exists()){
    System.out.println("success");
}
else{
    System.out.println("fail");
}
```