# get absolute path of a file which is outside workspace in java

Tags: java, absolute-path

[image]

My java file is in harness folder. I need absolute path of folder bif_v3 which is inside parent directory.

Comment: Search first before asking questions. A simple google search of the question gives this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_getabsolutepath.htm

Comment: Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming). Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What is the reason, that you have tagged your question `java`? The fact that your file is `outside workspace in java`? Does it mean, that if it was inside java workspace, you wouldn't tag it as `java`?

Comment: @RakeshNair OP didn't say that he wants to do that programmaticaly

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't ask certainly what you want to do, I assume that you want to open a file programmatically from a file which is in `harness`. You can 'navigate' programmatically using the following methods:

```
File currentDir = new File("."); //this will be your current directory
File parentDir = currentDir.getParentFile(); //this is parent directory
File newFile = new File(parentDir,"Example.txt"); //this is file Example.txt placed in parent directory
File newFile = new File(parentDir,"bif/Example.txt"); //this is file Example.txt placed in parent directory's directory bif.
```

Comment: The way of obtaining the parent directory that you proposed gave me a null pointer exception. What worked for me is the following: `File parentDir = currentDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297046/7305715).